# Why does sort not work in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this array of rows that I try to sort alphabetically with the sortByTitle() function. The sort method I am pretty sure is OK but there must be something with where I am calling it that makes it not work and it does not mutate the array at all. It may be because of the lifecycle of react.

The sort on getRows() works perfectly.

```
  getHistory() {
    if (this.state.historyUser && this.state.historyUser.length) {
      return this.state.historyUser.map(x => {
        x.state = x.finishDate ? 'closed' : 'open';
        return x;
      });
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }

  getRows() {
    let rows = this.state.rows || this.getHistory();
    rows.sort((a, b) => b.creationDate - a.creationDate)
    return rows.map((x, j) => {
      return (
        <div key={j} className={`testTable__row testTable__test testTable__test--${x.state}`}>
          {this.allTypes.map((type, i) => {
            let value = type.className !== 'checks' ? x[type.prop] : x.checked;
            if (type.className === 'name') {
              value = (
                <a href={`/test/${x._id}#1`}>{x[type.prop]}</a>
              );
            }
            return (
              <CellUser
                key={i}
                id={x._id}
                value={value}
                className={type.className}
                changeChecked={this.changeChecked}
                isSimulacro={x.isSimulacro}
                score={x.scoreProMIR}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  handleInputChange(e) {
    let rows = this.state.historyUser;
    const selector = e.target.getAttribute("label")
    rows = rows.filter(elm => elm[selector].toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase()));
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value, rows: rows});
  }

  sortByTitle() {
    let rows = this.state.rows || this.getHistory();
    rows.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
    this.setState({ rows: row });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
        <div className="testTable">
          <div className="testTable__row testTable__header">
            <div className="testTable__column testTable__column--name"> 
              Nombre 
              <input type="text" label="title" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
              <button onClick={this.sortByTitle}> Ordenar </button>
            </div>
            <div className="testTable__column testTable__column--score"> Nota </div>
            <div className="testTable__column testTable__column--type"> Tipo </div>
            <div className="testTable__column testTable__column--date"> Fecha </div>
            <div className="testTable__column testTable__column--state"> Estado </div>
            <div className="testTable__column testTable__column--checks">
              <label>
                Abiertos <Checkbox selected={this.state.checkOpen} onClick={this.allOpened} />
              </label>
              <label>
                Cerrados <Checkbox selected={this.state.checkClose} onClick={this.allClosed} />
              </label>
              <label>
                Todos <Checkbox selected={this.state.selectedAllRows} onClick={this.allRows} />
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="testTable__body">
            <Scrollbars {...scrollbarsProps()}>{this.getRows()}</Scrollbars>
          </div>

          <div
            className={`testTable__row testTable__footer${
              this.state.btnClose || this.state.btnReset || this.state.btnReopen ? ' active' : ''
            }`}
          >
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
              component="div"
              transitionName="topBottom"
              transitionEnterTimeout={0}
              transitionLeaveTimeout={0}
            >
              {this.state.btnClose ? (
                <button className="button button--close" onClick={this.requestAction} name="close">
                  Cerrar seleccionados
                </button>
              ) : null}
              {this.state.btnReset ? (
                <button className="button button--reset" onClick={this.requestAction} name="reset">
                  Resetear seleccionados
                </button>
              ) : null}
              {this.state.btnReopen ? (
                <button className="button button--open" onClick={this.requestAction} name="open">
                  Reabrir seleccionados
                </button>
              ) : null}
              {this.state.btnAddToStats ? (
                <button className="button button--add" onClick={this.requestAction} name="add">
                  Añadir a estadísticas
                </button>
              ) : null}
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
            component="div"
            transitionName="topBottom"
            className={`superCoverMsg${this.state.confirmAction ? '' : ' none'}`}
            transitionEnterTimeout={0}
            transitionLeaveTimeout={0}
          >
            {this.state.confirmAction ? (
              <div className="coverMsg confirmPopUp" key="0">
                <p>{this.state.textAction}</p>
                <div className="coverLabelInput coverLabelInput__botones columnWidth">
                  <ul className="cien">
                    <li className="cincuenta cancelar">
                      <a onClick={this.removeConfirmAction} href="#" title="Cancelar">
                        Cancelar
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="cincuenta aceptar">
                      <a onClick={this.aceptAction} href="#" title="Aceptar">
                        Aceptar
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            ) : null}
          </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your setting rows equal to row, which I don't see defined. Maybe change this

```js
this.setState({ rows: row });
```

to

```js
this.setState({ rows: rows });
```

Also I think the react-friendly way to modify an array from state would be use a spread operator so as not to mutate the state object directly, like so:

```js
let rows = [...this.state.rows] || this.getHistory();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sortByTitle() {
    let rows = this.state.rows || this.getHistory();
    rows.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
    this.setState({ rows: row });
}
```

You are mutating the state. instead copy the content into separate new array, sort it and use that new variable in `.setState`.